# EF - Querying on distinct derived class

Tags: entity-framework

I have a base class **Equipment**, and derived types of equipment in my EDM. What I would like to do is have the ability for the user to query in the UI the equipment list based on the **TYPE** of equipment. This means I would need to present a list of the **DISTINCT** derived types of equipment that they can choose from, and then return the results.

I am trying to think of the best way to do this. I was thinking of perhaps getting a list of distinct derived types, and showing this list to the user, but I do not know how I can query EF for this information. Any ideas/design help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is inheritance justified here? It looks like it would be easier to have `Equipment` only, with a reference to some `EquipmentType` entity. Inheritance would be justified if the types are significantly different, either in properties or in behaviour.

Comment: You may be right, I am using my normal software design principles with entity framework, and maybe that is not a good idea. Some pieces of equipment are complicated and hold other equipment inside them though, so I don't know if removing inheritance would be a good idea.

Comment: I don't know either, but inheritance makes it harder to do what you want. You can get the subtypes of `Equipment` through reflection, but I'm not sure if you want to present these technical names in the UI.